# Can we use LBPH in opencv to implement face Verification/Authentication System?

Tags: opencv, verification, lbph-algorithm

Recently, i try to implement face Verification/Authentication System using FaceRecognizer.LBPH as a face recognizer but it just indentifies well, not works for one-to-one matching.
Specifically, my training data set has 4 persons and my testing data set has 6 person(2 persons are used as imposters).when i use images of 2 imposters, the system went wrong.My code below, reference to [this link](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition)

```
const char *facerecAlgorithm ="FaceRecognizer.LBPH";
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model;
vector<Mat> preprocessedFaces;
int identity = -1;
..........
identity = model->predict(preprocessedFace);
cout << "Identity: " << identity << endl;
```

i expect the result as -1 when i test with 2 imposters.Any suggestion is appreciate.

Comment: apologies for accidentally blocking you on answers.opencv.org, can you try again ?

Comment: I am trying to implement his clue...You face with same problem, don't u?